# tf.keras shape ambiguation with lambda functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` layer which uses `tf` functions.  Why is it that sometimes I have to specify `output_shape=()` for my `Lambda` call and other times I do not?

Example

```py
freqDomain = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.fft2d,
                                    output_shape=(None, tileSize, tileSize, 1))(cpxInput) # Won't work unless output_shape is specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Keras specifically around `tf.ff2td` right now.

Keras can't automatically calculate the output shape for fft2d functions at the moment based on the input, so `output_shape` needs to be specified.  It's something that the developers will be working on:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12121#issuecomment-457217337

Comment: It turns out that if I don't do the backprop step, but simply run the model forward.  I don't need the output_shape.  Are you aware of this?